# Where statement in my query is supposed to return only today's and yesterday's dates, but is still returning earlier dates

Tags: sql

I am looking to only retrieve data from the past 24 hours. The WHERE statement I am using, in theory, should retrieve only from those productiondates. However, I am still having week-old productiondates returned. Any thoughts on how to improve this, or am I doing it wrong? I am using periscope.

```
select example1, 
    example2, 
    example3,
    productiondate,
    example4, 
    example5
from final
where exampleX = exampleY or exampleX is null
and productiondate  > DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())
and example1 <> 'XXX'
and example2 <> 'YYY'
and example2 <> 'ZZZ'
  
order by 2
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is your `OR`.  It conflicts with the other `ANDs` and pulls in more records outside of your required query.  If you need the `OR`, consider some parantheses to contain it.

Comment: Im relatively new to SQL, how would i format the parentheses

Comment: I don't know all what's needed for your `WHERE` condition, but possibly all you need is parantheses around the first part like this... `(exampleX = exampleY or exampleX is null)`.

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Logical operator precedence in SQL can be surprising. You need parentheses around the `OR`.

```
where (exampleX = exampleY or exampleX is null)
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
where coalesce(exampleX, exampleY) = exampleY
```